# Why is dimension of vector in Python (N,) instead of (N,1)?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, tuples

In Python, I am writing code that, at some point, deals with a matrix (which could be a vector) `X` and considers its dimensions. I want to store each dimension in variables `m` and `n` respectively.

If the matrix `X` is a vector of size `N x 1`, then `np.shape(X)` will return the output as `(N,)`. However, this information is not helpful because when I store it as `m,n = np.shape(X)`, I encounter the error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue? Ideally, I would like to store `m = N, n = 1`, but I don't know how to achieve that. I thought about reshaping my vector like `X = np.reshape(X, (np.shape(X)[0], 1))`, but that might cause further issues in the subsequent code.

Any suggestions for this? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I don't quite understand. You have an array of shape `(N,)` but want it to be of shape `(N, 1)`?

Comment: Yeah, I mean I just want that extra 1 to appear, because then I can store the dimensions of my matrix as m, n = np.shape(X)

Comment: Why don't you just do `n = X.shape[1] if X.ndim == 2 else 1 `?

Comment: Because I actually didn't know ndim option existed. And that definitely solves the problem! And sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: Ah ok, no worries, I was just unsure if you were aware of that option

Comment: `len(X.shape)` is another way of getting at this `ndim`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is dimension of vector in Python (N,) instead of (N,1)?

Both are available in Python via [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). The former is to be be seen as a 1-dimensional sequence of numbers a.k.a. flat array, while the latter must prealably be shaped explicitly to be multidimensional. Check for yourself:

```py
>>> X = np.arange(3)
>>> X
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> X.shape
(3,)
```

*versus*

```py
>>> Y = X.reshape((-1, 1))  # or X[:, np.newaxis]
>>> Y
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
>>> Y.shape
(3, 1)
```

---

To ***indifferently*** deal with flat or shaped arrays, i.e. without having to reshape anything, you can proceed as follows:

```py
m, n, *_ = (*X.shape, 1)
```

An example with a flat array

```py
>>> X        = np.arange(10)
>>> m, n, *_ = (*X.shape, 1)
>>> m, n
(10, 1)
```

An example with a rectangular matrix

```py
>>> X        = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
>>> m, n, *_ = (*X.shape, 1)  # <-- The approach
>>> m, n
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

When NumPy deals with one-dimensional arrays or vectors and returns a tuple with a single element, it presents it in the format `(5,)` rather than just `(5)`. This formatting with a comma after the value, such as `(5,)`, is utilized to indicate that it's a tuple, not just a value without parentheses.

The issue arises when `np.shape(X)` returns a single-element tuple for one-dimensional arrays. Trying to unpack it, such as `m, n = np.shape(X)`, triggers an error as Python expects two values for unpacking but receives only one, resulting in the "not enough values to unpack" error.

To circumvent this issue, one can utilize the `np.shape(X)` method to determine the number of elements in the array's dimensions and add the necessary dimensions if required.

Here's an example function that addresses this problem:

```py
def dim(matrix, required_dims=2):
    shape = np.shape(matrix)
    if len(shape) < required_dims:
        shape += (1,) * (required_dims - len(shape))
    return shape
```

This function adds the required number of dimensions to the `shape` tuple based on `required_dims`, ensuring proper dimensionality even for one-dimensional arrays.

Example usage:

```
matrix = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
result = dim(matrix, required_dims=3)
print(result)  # Output: (5, 1, 1)
```

For your case you can use:

```
m, n = dim(matrix)
```

---

If desired, you can remove the conditional `if` statement in this function:

```py
def dim(matrix, required_dims=2):
    shape = np.shape(matrix)
    shape += (1,) * (required_dims - len(shape))
    return shape
```

---

If you only need to handle vectors, you can use this function:

```py
def dim(matrix):
    shape = np.shape(matrix)
    return shape if len(shape) > 1 else (shape[0], 1)
```

This function returns the unchanged dimensions for matrices that are not vectors and adds an additional dimension describing the second unit, otherwise.

Comment: See: [`numpy.squeeze()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html#numpy.squeeze), [`numpy.expand_dims()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html#numpy.expand_dims) instead of rolling your own?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AKX for the tip.

By using `np.expand_dims`, you can avoid the error you encounter when trying to unpack the dimensions of the vector. Here's how you can do it:

```py
import numpy as np

# Your vector X
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])  # Example vector, replace it with your own
print("X:", X)

# Obtaining dimensions using np.shape
shape = np.shape(X)
print("X shape:", shape)

# Checking if X is a vector
if len(shape) == 1:
    # If it's a vector, add a new axis
    X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=1)  # Adding a second dimension axis
    print("Expanded X:", X)
    print("Expanded X shape:", np.shape(X))

# Now the dimensions can be unpacked without errors
m, n = np.shape(X)

# Displaying the results
print("m =", m)  # Number of rows
print("n =", n)  # Number of columns (in this case for a vector, it will be 1)
```

This code verifies if `X` is a vector (i.e., if it has one dimension), and if so, it introduces a new axis using `np.expand_dims`.

The ouput of the code:

```
X: [1 2 3 4]
X shape: (4,)
Expanded X: [[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]
Expanded X shape: (4, 1)
m = 4
n = 1
```

Note that using this approach, accessing elements within the vector will require two indexing operations:

```py
print(X[0])  # Output - an array consisting of one element
print(X[0][0])  # You can obtain the element like this
print(X[0, 0])  # or like this
```

Output:

```
[1]
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check the dimensionality of a Numpy array is just to use `ndim` property on the array. For example, at the Python console:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.ndim
1
>>> b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> b.ndim
2
```

You can use this to switch your logic between vector/1- and matrix/2-dimensional array processing:

```py
def process(X):
  if X.ndim == 1:
    # ... vector processing ...
  elif X.ndim == 2:
    # ... matrix processing ...
  else:
    raise ValueError(f"Too many dimensions: {X.ndim}")
```

One thing to keep in mind is that Numpy (and Python's underlying array structures) have a distinction between single dimensional arrays and two dimensional arrays where one of the dimensions has a length of 1.

So an array of dimension `(N)` (represented in Python output as `(N,)`) is different to an array with dimension `(N, 1)` or `(1, N)`. Some examples to illustrate:

```py
>>> np.shape([1, 2, 3])
(3,)
>>> np.shape([[1], [2], [3]])
(3, 1)
>>> np.shape([[1, 2, 3]])
(1, 3)
```

So I would suggest you avoid dynamically changing array dimensions in your code unless you really know what you're doing. Instead, select the most appropriate data structures for the problem you're trying to solve and make sure your input and output formats match that structure.